# Calculator within Node Editor

Tags: texturing, node-editor, mathematics

I am working on a project with multiple texture of different sizes for the same object. The textures have the correct scale in dpi.

I use a formula to calculate the UV scale of each texture.
"pixel width of Texture" **Divided by** "DPI"
**Multiplied by** "2.54" (inch to cm)
**Divided by** "Width in cm of object's UV"

You gave me an answer using the MixRGB and Texture Cooridinate Nodes to create the vector. This is great for square textures.

What if the textures are rectangular. How do I create a vector with two input?

[image]

Thanks

EDIT

Not sure how to update the post. Just wanted to post the latest solution. This also resolves the issue of non uniform textures.

[image]

Basically, the first part gets the scale of the texture. (Math nodes)
The second part scales the UV x and y axis. (Separate and Combine RBG)

Now i can input the dpi of the image, pixel height and width, and the UV dimension in cm. The textures all textures will be at the correct proportional.

I don't know the correct term for UV dimension in cm.

Comment: Found the answer.

The two outputs need to be separated with  'Separate RGB' node than Combined with one 'Combine RGB' node.
Now connect the green height calculation to the GREEN 'Combine RGB' node.
And the red height calculation to the RED 'Combine RGB' node.
Leave Blue at 0

There you go. 

Hope I was clear.